# Bulk Transaction Processing - Auto Pay Scenario

Tags: authorize.net

We are using Authorize.net for our payment (credit card & ach) processing and implementing an auto-pay feature for our billing system.

Is there a way to process cards (payment profiles stored by authorize.net) in bulk and get a callback with the results instead of calling the api for every profile that needs to be charged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorize.Net does not offer a bulk payment API. They do offer a [bulk payment upload](https://www.authorize.net/content/dam/anet-redesign/documents/uploadguide.pdf) but it does not offer support for payment profiles.

Comment: Thank you @John, you confirmed what I found